# How to find greater than a number that should be a Fascinating number ,

Tags: c++

Fascinating Number:-

Hey find any four digit number fascinating that has all the 4 digits unique. For example 1234 is a fascinating number. His friend Rahul gave him N numbers and asks him to find the minimum number which is strictly larger than the given one and has only distinct digits.

Input format
The first line of the input contains integer N, denoting the count of numbers provided by Rahul.
Each of the next N lines contains one integer.

Output format
Print the next fascinating number.

Constraints
1<=N<=10

1000<=number<=9000

Time Limit
1 second

Example
Input

2

1234

2010

Output

1235

2013

Sample test case explanation, 1235 is the minimum number that is larger than 1234 with all 4 digits 1,2,3,5 distinct.

Please can anyone help, my approach is to take a number from user and find out all the digits and check whether they are equal or not, if they aren't equal then add +1 in the digit.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N,num;
    cin>>num;
    int first_digit,second_digit,third_digit,fourth_digit;
    fourth_digit=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    third_digit=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    second_digit=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    first_digit=num%10;
    
    while (first_digit==second_digit || first_digit==third_digit || first_digit==fourth_digit || second_digit==first_digit||second_digit==third_digit||second_digit==fourth_digit || third_digit==first_digit|| third_digit==second_digit|| third_digit==fourth_digit || fourth_digit==first_digit || fourth_digit==second_digit || fourth_digit==third_digit)
    {
    if (first_digit == second_digit)
    {
        second_digit=second_digit+1;
    }
    else if(first_digit == third_digit)
    {
        third_digit=third_digit+1;
    }
    else if(first_digit == fourth_digit)
    {
        fourth_digit=fourth_digit+1;
    }
    
    if (second_digit == first_digit)
    {
        second_digit=second_digit+1;
    }
    else if(second_digit == third_digit)
    {
        third_digit=third_digit+1;
    }
    else if(second_digit == fourth_digit)
    {
        fourth_digit=fourth_digit+1;
    }
    
    if (third_digit == first_digit)
    {
        third_digit=third_digit+1;
    }
    else if(third_digit == second_digit)
    {
        third_digit=third_digit+1;
    }
    else if(third_digit == fourth_digit)
    {
        fourth_digit=fourth_digit+1;
    }
    
    
    if (fourth_digit == first_digit)
    {
        fourth_digit=fourth_digit+1;
    }
    else if(fourth_digit == second_digit)
    {
        fourth_digit=fourth_digit+1;
    }
    else if(fourth_digit == third_digit)
    {
        fourth_digit=fourth_digit+1;
    }
    
    }
    cout<<first_digit<<second_digit<<third_digit<<fourth_digit;   
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't spam tags. Don't use so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites as any kind of learning or teaching resource, despite what anyone claim or say. Their only purpose is for experienced programmers to spend a little free time when they have nothing better to do.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Where can I get my queries to be sorted related to programming?

Comment: "Where can I get my queries to be solved related to programming?" That's here, you're in the right place for that. But this isn't a "competition" site, neither is it a tutorial or learning resource (like those sites). You can ask questions about programming, the more specific the better, but you also have to include more details than you do. For example, for some specific input, what is the expected and actual behavior (as well as output)? What efforts of debugging have you done? What are your own thoughts about the problem? Please read the links I provided, to help you write better questions.

Comment: I mentioned each and everything about the question I am stucked in including inputs and outputs.
Please, if you know about C++ then help me in this question. I am getting frustrated. Stucked in this from an hour

Answer (score 0):

Their are many mistakes in the code let me point them so you check and try it yourself

> Mistakes which i noticed

> 1.What are u exactly checking in the while condition (your intention is to check weather the number digits are unique or not but when u give a unique input then it will never go inside the while loop)

> 2. When their is a digit like 9 when u add 1 to it it becomes 10 and 10 will appended please try other approach when its 9 (hint increase the previous digit by 1 and move that 9 to zero)  [example if number is 2039  you code will make it 20310 which is wrong if u try increased the before number which means 2049 and replacing 9 with 0 and again as 0 is duplicate repeat until u get unique numbers]

Hope this explanation helps!

> (Remember these things(Few suggestions))
>
> 1. If this question is from a competition of codding post the questions after competition
> 2. If you just want direct code from here this is not the correct place!

Comment: It's just practice question, I am not posting anything from any competition or so.

Comment: Is my approach is right?

Comment: Have you looked into the points posted in this answer?

Comment: @EmmaBrown as ur a beginner ur 1st goal should be getting the required output so ur approach is fine for now. Looks into the above mentioned mistakes and try resolving them...

Comment: It is a practice question, not a question from any competition or so.
But I still not able to write appropriate code for this.